# Neo4j, consequetive MATCH path queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was trying to write a Cypher query with multiple matches in order to get multiple paths

Query

```
MATCH (a:A) --> (b:B) where b.uid="asdfas"
MATCH path = (a) -> (leaf) with collect(path) as paths
MATCH another_path = (b) -> (leaf) with collect(another_path) as paths_2

RETURN paths, paths_2
```

Result

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `paths` not defined 
"RETURN paths, paths_2"
```

The return clause  forgets about the `path`

Unlike above, if the MATCH only results in Nodes rather than list of paths

```
MATCH (a:A) --> (b:B) where b.uid="asdfas"
MATCH path = (a) -> (leaf) with collect(path) as paths
MATCH (b) --> (c:C) 

RETURN paths, c
```

The above query executes perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `WITH` clause causes all existing variables to become unbound *except for* the variables the `WITH` clause passes onwards.

The first `WITH` must pass `b`, so that the following `MATCH` can use it. And the second `WITH` must pass `paths` so that it can be returned:

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B) WHERE b.uid="asdfas"
MATCH path = (a)->()
WITH b, COLLECT(path) AS paths
MATCH another_path = (b)->()
WITH paths, COLLECT(another_path) AS paths_2
RETURN paths, paths_2
```

Even better, your second `WITH` is not actually needed:

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B) WHERE b.uid="asdfas"
MATCH path = (a)->()
WITH b, COLLECT(path) AS paths
MATCH another_path = (b)->()
RETURN paths, COLLECT(another_path) AS paths_2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, you need to add `paths` to your final `with` statement for it to be available to the `RETURN` statement.

`MATCH another_path = (b) -> (leaf) with collect(another_path) as paths_2, paths`

Personally, I like to put `WITH` (and `WHERE`) statements on separate lines to make these things potentially more clear as to what is being passed on

```
MATCH (a:A) --> (b:B) 
WHERE b.uid="asdfas"

MATCH path = (a) -> (leaf) 
WITH collect(path) as paths

MATCH another_path = (b) -> (leaf) 
WITH collect(another_path) as paths_2, paths

RETURN paths, paths_2
```

Comment: As in the above answer(which is marked correct), node "b" shall be passed along with "paths". Otherwise (b) will match every node in the database.